# Events from AngularJS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

How can I broadcast event from AngularJS and listen this event in basic JS script. Thank you

Comment: We need some code.

Comment: what did you want to do ? avoid using Jquery with Angular specially for editing the DOM

Comment: I connected to sockets with angularJS and I have some app with basic JS. so I need call function from my js code when sockets come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body data-ng-app="AngularApp">

  <script>
    //my custom native JS Script 


    //normal Javscript function , can be called within AngularJS normally
    function someJsFunction(){
      console.log('this is some JS function');
    }



    // some Event handling and listentning to be fired wihtin AngularJS
    function Event(sender) {
        this._sender = sender;
        this._listeners = [];
    }

    Event.prototype = {
        attach: function (listener) {
            this._listeners.push(listener);
        },
        notify: function (args) {
            var index;

            for (index = 0; index < this._listeners.length; index += 1) {
                this._listeners[index](this._sender, args);
            }
        }
    };



    //Event Handling Usage 
    var myCutstomEvent = new Event(this);

    myCutstomEvent.attach( function() {
      console.log('myCustomEvent Handler');
    });



  </script>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="clickBtn()" value="clickme"/>
  </div>

</body>
```

.....
and the Angular Code

```
var app = angular.module("AngularApp", []);

app.controller(
  'myCtrl',  ['$scope',  'myService',
   function($scope, myService) {

     $scope.clickBtn = function(){
           console.log('buttonClicked in Controller');
            //call service
            myService.someService();

            //fire normal Angular Event
            $scope.$broadcast('myCustomAngularEvent');
        };


        //handle Angular Event and refire the JS Event 
        $scope.$on('myCustomAngularEvent', function () {
            //Fire the JS Event 
             myCutstomEvent.notify();
         })

}]);


app.service('myService', function() {

   var someService = function() {
      console.log('this is someService');
      someJsFunction();   
    };

    var services = {
      'someService' : someService
    };

    return services;
});
```

...
and the console will show this :

```
 buttonClicked in Controller
 this is someService
 this is some JS function
 myCustomEvent Handler
```

cheers